# How to make JavaScript indexOf() not detect substring

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

Here are two if conditions with different checks:

CASE 1:

```
if(plan_name.indexOf("T1")>=0 && plan_name.indexOf("FLEX")>=0 && plan_name.indexOf("Non-VAE")>=0) {
    //do something
}
```

followed by (in same code/program)

CASE 2:

```
if(plan_name.indexOf("T1")>=0 && plan_name.indexOf("Non-FLEX")>=0 && plan_name.indexOf("Non-VAE")>=0){
    //do something
}
```

Here is the input to which above conditions get applied:

**plan name** = `iOS 7.7 - RC - T1 - Non-FLEX, Non-VAE`

In my code everytime the first `if` condition in CASE 1 is becoming valid because indexOf() is detecting the substring and not the `actual specific` string that I want the code to detect(that is CASE 2 should be valid). How to make such specific string match in JS?

Comment: *if* is not a loop :)

Comment: My bad, fixed ...changed to conditions

Comment: So you need to rip it apart and compare the pieces

Comment: And how do you suppose that would work? The string `FLEX` is part of `Non-FLEX` and will always match, if you don't want to match, you'll need to add characters, even if those characters are spaces *(hint)*.

Comment: split on spaces and go through resultant array and compare

Comment: @charlietfl - or just `indexOf(" FLEX")`

Comment: should the word FLEX starts the string?

Comment: First do the second check, and only in the `else` part do the first check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is split it apart and see if the string matches in the array

```
var str = "iOS 7.7 - RC - T1 - Non-FLEX, Non-VAE";
var parts = str.split(/[\s,]/g);
console.log("FLEX", parts.indexOf("FLEX")!==-1);
console.log("Non-FLEX", parts.indexOf("Non-FLEX")!==-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to reorder your execution flow:

```
if(plan_name.indexOf("T1")>=0 && 
      plan_name.indexOf("Non-FLEX")>=0 &&
      plan_name.indexOf("Non-VAE")>=0){
    ...
} else if(plan_name.indexOf("T1")>=0 && 
      plan_name.indexOf("FLEX")>=0 &&
      plan_name.indexOf("Non-VAE")>=0) {
   ...
}
```

As the first condition is stricter than the second, the second one will only be checked if the first one is not true.

However, this only works if there are no more options, because if you have to look also for `'VAE'` and `'Non-VAE'`, then maybe you should "tokenize" the string: as it seems the tokens are separated by spaces, you could split it and then look in the resulting array for each token you need.

A third option, still assuming that the tokens are separated by spaces is adding a space to your matcher: instead of 'FLEX' look for `' FLEX'` and `' Non-Flex'`

Answer (score 0):

your check should be like this

```
plan_name.indexOf("T1")>=-1
```

not this

```
plan_name.indexOf("T1")>=0
```